# delete object instance of a class- NodeJS

Tags: node.js, oop

i have created the class , and initialised it, also i have added the timer function inside the class, then i explicitly called class instance to null, still that timer function is running,  my question is how do i delete the class instance from memory? , and how do i invalidate timer after class is null

my code is as follows

```
class Person {
    constructor() {
      this.id = 'id_1';
    }
    timers(){
    const intervalObj = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('interviewing the interval');
      }, 3000);
    }
  }

  var justAGuy = new Person();
  justAGuy.timers()
  justAGuy = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a garbage collected language.  You don't and can't explicitly delete objects.  Instead, you clear any references to the object so that no code can ever reach the object.  That will make it eligible for garbage collection and the garbage collector will then remove it from memory on a future GC pass.

In your object, you also have to stop the interval timer because as long as it is running, then your object may be kept alive because the timer callback has access to `this` which refers to the object.

```
class Person {
     constructor() {
       this.id = 'id_1';
     }
     timers(){
        stop();
        this.intervalObj = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('interviewing the interval');
        }, 3000);
     }
     stop() {
         if (this.intervalObj) {
             clearInterval(this.intervalObj);
             this.intervalObj = null;
         }
     }

}

var justAGuy = new Person();
justAGuy.timers();
justAGuy.stop();
justAGuy = null;
```

Comment: ok ,but how can we know that the garbage collection is done for that class instance And it is no longer in memory ?

Comment: @bhushandeshmukh - You don't.  It gets cleaned up when it's no longer in use.  Why do you need to know exactly when it's cleared?  Any object running an interval timer always need to clean up its interval timer when its job is done.  Even if the object wasn't going to be GCed, you don't want timers running that aren't needed any more as that's just wasted resources/CPU.  That's just appropriate housekeeping in your use of resources.

Comment: i just wanted to know, not any specific  reason ,thanks ,i will keep this in mind